# Display Image from index 0 of array react native

Tags: reactjs, firebase, image, react-native

I am using firebase and react native for an app. The posts are saved so that the field "images" is an array of multiple images. But I want to display the first image only(index 0) and couldn't get it to work.

Help would be very much appreciated

```
   return ( 
      <View style={styles.container}>
        

        <View style={styles.gallery}>
            <FlatList
                numColumns={3}
                horizontal={false}
                data={posts}
                renderItem={({ item }) => (
                    <View
                        style={styles.imageContainer}>

                        <Text>{item.name}</Text>
                        <TouchableOpacity 
                                onPress={() => props.navigation.navigate('PostPage', { postId: item.id})}>
                        <Image
                                style={styles.image}
                                source={{ uri: item.images[0] }} //-> fetched from firebase firestore
                                />
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                    </View>

                )}

            />
        </View>
    </View>

  )
  }
```

Comment: Can you please share the structure of an  `item` in `posts`

Comment: a nested object like this : {name:'Name', description:'Description', images:['http://link1.co', 'http://link2.co', 'http://link3.co'] - I fetch all data from firestore and usestate to set it to posts, and i only need the first element of images array

Comment: What is the error that you are facing?. I'm assuming the image array has valid URLs in it

Comment: it throws the following error when i try to call the uri:item.images[0] -> undefined is not an object( evaluating item.images[0])

Comment: For example, if I add another field in firestore doc called image and just pass the string with the url, it displays. But I need it to be displayed from an array

Comment: Are you sure you do not have `undefined` entries in your list of posts? It looks like item is undefined in at least one case.

Comment: What do you exactly mean by that? @baumstumpf

Comment: The error message is saying it can't access the key `images` in `item`, because `item` is undefined. That probably means that your list of posts does contain at least one entry that is `undefined`.
I would try to `console.log(posts)` above the return and check if all the entries are valid posts.

Comment: I agree with @baumstumpf. Can you please try adding a check if your item is valid or it contains `images` array, and display the image only if the condition is satisfied. otherwise fill it with a placeholder image.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys! Just checked and you were right. Only 2 of the 8 posts i'm currently testing with had "images" field in firestore. Added to all and works fine now. Weird tho, because if I get image source from item.image (a single string containing img url) it doesn't have any prob if other posts are missing this field

Comment: Ah, perfect. I thought the item is undefined, but the images can be undefined as well. The issue then is that accessing the first entry `[0]` of the images crashes. In the other case you have no imageUrl to render but nothing crashes. You just don't see an image then.